# beautifulsoup get href only in a certain class from google

Tags: python, hyperlink, beautifulsoup, href

I would like to get only the ten links from google, (I think where the class is... ?

```
<cite class="_Od">
https://www.
<b>python</b>
.org/
</cite>
<div class="action-menu ab_ctl">
<a id="am-b0" class="clickable-dropdown-arrow ab_button" data-ved="0CC4Q7B0wAA"
role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" jsaction="ab.tdd
keydown:ab.hbke;  keypress:ab.mskpe" aria-label="Result details" href="#">
<div class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" data-ved="0CC8QqR8wAA" tabindex="-1" 
role="menu" jsaction="keydown:ab.hdke;mouseover:ab.hdhne;mouseout:ab.hdhue">
```

I know how to get all the anchor tags, but I don't know how to get only the anchor tags which are in that Od Class?

```
anchor = soup.find_all('a')
for a in anchor:
print a
```

**UPDATE**

Got the following error...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-248b7ec4fbed> in <module>()
  8 s = soup.prettify()
  9 
---> 10 atags = soup.find('cite', {'class': '_Od'}).findAll('a')
  11 for tag in atags:
  12     print tag
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Comment: Just a note, that class is generated and is likely to change every time google does a code push.

Comment: no problem anthony, i'm just using this as an example to practice my skills - get all the data, say from a tags, or a certain class, then get the hrefs from that class and print the ten of them. But thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Also if you're familiar with css selectors, `PyQuery` might suit you better.  The pyquery solution is `PyQuery(dom).find('._Od a')`. (`pip install pyquery`)

Comment: `bs4` has css selectors.  `soup.select('._Od a'`)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just narrow down your search a bit (find the class) and get the children (a tags) (of course, your snippet does not appear to have any `<a>` tags in there, so nothing would be found):

```
atags = soup.find('cite', {'class': '_Od'}).findAll('a')
for tag in atags:
    print tag
```

**Edit** (sorry for omitting this before)

What this does is find the first `cite` tag with the class `_Od` and use that as the base to find all contained `a` tags.

Comment: thanks nerdwaller, my ipython says its having trouble with ".findAll('a')"

is your code basically finding all the cite tags, where they have a class OD, and are in a anchor element, i didn't expect to see the find('cite' part I'm not sure what that does?

Comment: @yoshiserry - Updated. Not sure what issue you're having (other than maybe cite not being found, thus `findAll` not a member of NoneType perhaps?), it would be helpful if you'd give that. Works fine in local tests I tried.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I am getting --> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-248b7ec4fbed> in <module>()
      8 s = soup.prettify()
      9 
---> 10 atags = soup.find('cite', {'class': '_Od'}).findAll('a')
     11 for tag in atags:
     12     print tag

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Comment: I made that HTML you provided valid before trying it, so maybe that has something to do with it. I'm no longer near my computer to test it as you posted, however. So it would be smarter to get the `cite` tag and verify it is not `None` and continue on your way.

Comment: how did you make the HTML I had VALID before trying your answer? I'm not sure what that involves (making it valid)?

Comment: <html><head></head><body>**your content**</body></html>. I.e. likely the way you would get it back from scraping it originally.

Comment: so did you write this to a file? I.e. how di dyou get the two <html><head> tags that I didn't have in their?

Comment: You're kidding, right? I answered your question. Now I'd suggest doing some additional research into accomplishing the other parts you needed to get to where you can use it. Id avoid hardcoding it or loading from a file, since an html parser is pretty unnecessary on static info you manually get.